# What am I seeing returned here when applying .characters to a string?

Tags: string, swift, character

In reading the official documentation for Swift, I have discovered that it is possible to return some kind of data structure containing the characters of a string by using `.characters`. I can then iterate through whatever is returned from this and print each character in the string seperately, as I have in my for loop below.

```
var myString = "bananas"

for character in myString.characters{
    print(character)
}

print (myString.characters)
```

My question is: what is actually being returned when I use `.characters`, and why, when I try to print the full set of characters, do I see this:

`CharacterView(_core: Swift._StringCore(_baseAddress: 0x000000010025bc3a, _countAndFlags: 7, _owner: nil))`?

What exactly is a `CharacterView`, and why would it be better for `.characters` to return this, and not just, for example, an array containing the individual characters as elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `CharacterView` is a way of referencing a `String`'s collection of `Character`s. We can create a new `String` from a `CharacterView` and turn a `CharacterView` into an `Array` of `Character`s. We can also do many of the same things we would with an `Array` with a `CharacterView`. Although it is not a fully-fledged `Array<Character>` and cannot for example be tested for equality without first being transformed into an actual `Array` (or be printed in the same way).

```
let str = "string"
var chars = str.characters

Array(chars) == Array(str.characters) // true

chars.insert("s", atIndex: chars.endIndex)
chars[chars.startIndex.advancedBy(2)] // r

Array(chars) == Array(str.characters) // false
str // "string"

String(chars) // "strings"
Array(chars) // ["s", "t", "r", "i", "n", "g", "s"]
```

But when we change what is contained in a `CharacterView` it does not change the string itself (nor its `CharacterView`). This makes it look rather nonsensical and that it should simply be an Array. However, Swift has many types like this that help with memory management.

Think of it like this: if we want to access the characters in a String and simply inspect them then there is no need for a copy to be made and for more memory to be consumed. So Swift can provide us with a reference to the `Character`s. However, if we want to make changes to the `CharacterView` then is the time for a copy to be made. The `CharacterView` therefore provides Swift with a way to decide when a copy is appropriate.

This is similar to `ArraySlice` when we use subscripting with an `Array`. The memory location of the `Slice` points to the same location as the `Array` until a change is made and then it is time for Swift to make its copy.

**tl;dr** For the purposes of memory management `CharacterView` can be thought as a hybrid between a `reference` and `value` type. But when programming we can think of it as a straightforward `value` type and not worry about anything going on under the hood.

> Behind the scenes, Swift’s compiler optimizes string usage so that
>   actual copying takes place only when absolutely necessary. This means
>   you always get great performance when working with strings as value
>   types. ([Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH7-ID285))

We can test this to be true by doing the following inside a playground

```
let str = "string"
var chars = str.characters

print(chars)
print(str.characters)

chars.append("s")
print(chars)
```

and inspecting the base addresses. We will find that the base address in the first two instances is the same, but once a change is made the base address changes.

Answer (score 0):

I think myString.characters is an `Array<Character>` - which is an array of  character types. A character type is just basically a one letter string/character as the name suggests.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH7-ID290

You can just do this for loop to get each character in the string (without the .characters):

```
for character in myString{
    print(character)
}
```